# How do I view my environment variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, terminal, environment-variables

I am trying to connect to my pusher server but am receiving the error:

> Missing client configuration: please check that key, secret and app_id are configured.

I want to check my environmental variables, but cannot find any clear way to do this on Stack Overflow yet.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Printing the Environment from the Shell

As other answers have pointed out, one can use `/usr/bin/env` or `/usr/bin/printenv` from the command line to see what the environment is in the shell before starting Rails, or in a subshell after starting it. For example:

1. `rails s` <kbd>RETURN</kbd>
2. <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd>
3. `env` <kbd>RETURN</kbd>
4. `fg` <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

### Displaying ENV from the View Layer

In Ruby, [ENV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/ENV.html) is a "hash-like" accessor for environment variables; it is *not* actually a Hash. You can introspect ENV from your Rails console easily enough simply by typing `ENV` or `ENV['foo']`, but sometimes you may want to see what Rails thinks the environment is during rendering. In that case, you want the [Rails debug helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debug). For example:

```
# ERB
<%= debug ENV.to_h.to_yaml %>

# HAML
= debug ENV.to_h.to_yaml
```

Calling #to_yaml to serialize the ENV object will make the output easier to read, but requires you to convert ENV to a hash or array first. You can also just invoke `debug ENV` without chaining; it's just harder on the eyes.

Comment: Thanks for this!

However, I'm noticing that variables I'm setting in .env.local don't seem to show up here... Any ideas why?

Answer (score 16):

Use command `ENV` in rails console. That will return a hash of your environmental values you can access. Alternatively, you can access your environmental variables from your apps root path using the same command and the variables will be returned formatted.

Comment: ENV isn't really a Hash. `ENV.class == Object`, and a number of Hash methods will not work on ENV unless you call #to_h on it first.

Answer (score 13):

Or use the O/S shell, in Ubuntu use

```
printenv
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Both of these commands will print to stdout your environment variables:

`env`

`printenv`

Answer (score 0):

I have also used the following in the view layer:

```
<% request.env.each do |key, value| %>
  <strong><%= key %></strong> => <%= value %><br/>
<% end %>
```

I found it very helpful to debug issues caused by env variables set at the passenger/nginx level, that would not show up when I used rails console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access variables in credentials.yml file, this is a really nice way:

```
Rails.application.credentials
```